# How to handle different organization with single DB?

Tags: database, database-design

**Background**
building an `online information system` which user can access through any computer. I don't want to replicate DB and code for every university or organization. 
I just want user to hit a domain like `www.example.com` sign in and use it. 
For second user it will also hit the same domain `www.example.com` sign in and use it.  but the data for them are different. 

**Scenario**

suppose a university has 200 employees, 2nd university has 150 and so on.
**Qusetion**

> Do i need to have separate employee table for each university or is it OK to have a single table with a column that has University ID?

I assume 2nd is best but Suppose i have 20 universities or organizations and a total of thousands of employees.

> What is the best approach?

This same thing is for all table? This is just to give you an example. 

Thanks

Comment: It's OK to have a single table with a column that has University ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach will depend upon the data, usage, and client requirements/restrictions.

1. Use an integrated model, as suggested by duffymo. This may be appropriate if each organization is part of a larger whole (i.e. all colleges are part of a state college board) and security concerns about cross-query access are minimal<sup>2</sup>. This approach has a minimal amount of separation between each organization as the same schema<sup>1</sup> and relations are "openly" shared. It leads to a very simple model initially, but it *can* become very complicated (with compound FKs and correct usage of such) if needing relations for organization-specific values because it adds another dimension of data.
2. [Implement multi-tenancy](https://web.archive.org/web/20110221085910/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). This can be achieved with implicit filters on the relations (perhaps hidden behinds views and store procedures), different schemas, or other database-specific support. Depending upon implementation this may or may not share schema or relations even though all data may reside in the same database. With implicit isolation, some complicated keys or relationships can be hidden/eliminated. Multi-tenancy isolation also generally makes it harder/impossible to cross-query.
3. [Silo the databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_silo) entirely. Each customer or "organization" has a separate database. This implies separate relations and schema groups. I have found this approach to to be relatively simple with automated tooling, but it does require managing multiple database. Direct cross-querying is impossible, although "linked databases" can be used if there is a need.

Even though it's not "a single DB", in our case, we had the following restrictions 1) not allowed to ever share/expose data between organizations, and 2) each organization wanted their own local database. Thus, our product ended up using a silo approach. Make sure that the approach chosen meets customer requirements.

None of these approaches will have any issue with "thousands", "hundreds of thousands", or even "millions" of records as long as the indices and queries are correctly planned. However, switching from one to another can violate many assumed constraints and so the decision should be made earlier on.

---

<sup>1</sup> In this response I am using "schema" to refer to the security grouping of database objects (e.g. tables, views) and not the database model itself. The actual database model used can be common/shared, as we do even when using separate databases.

<sup>2</sup> An integrated approach is not necessarily insecure - but it doesn't inherently have some of the built-in isolation of other designs.

Answer (score 2):

I would normalize it to have UNIVERSITY and EMPLOYEE tables, with a one-to-many relationship between them.

You'll have to take care to make sure that only people associated with a given university can see their data.  Role based access will be important.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a multi-tenant architecture. you should read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

I would go with Tenant Per Schema, which means copying the structure across different schemas, however, as you should keep all your SQL DDL in source control, this is very easy to script.

It's easy to screw up and "leak" information between tenants if doing it all in the same table.

Comment: thnx it was really helpful.